# How to export firestore data collection by collection field value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, collections, google-cloud-firestore, export, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export google firestore data in cloud storage location using the below command.

```
    gcloud firestore export gs://<bucketName>/<folderName> --collection-ids=<collectionName>
```

I would like to furthermore filter the collection by its field name value or date range, is it possible to do so? cloud function solution also welcome.

This is my js solution

````
  console.log('data export bucket', bucket);

  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
    process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    'project_name'
  );

  const response = await client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
      // or define a list of collection IDs:
      // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
      collectionIds: tables,
    });
  console.log('successfully exportToGCS', response);

}```
````

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, there is no such possibility within the Firestore export feature. These options come to my mind:

1) Since [exports and imports are charged at the same rate as read/write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#billing), I would suggest running a query in FS instead of using the export functionality. You can run such a query with regular Cloud Function as you are already proposing. Refer to [this guide for getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

2) In case you really need the Firestore/Datastore export format, there's an option to copy all filtered data to a new collection and exporting from there, but you'll probably pay far more then you'd want to.

Depending on what you want do you want to do with the data next, you can create a Cloud Function that will listen for changes and copy your filtered data to a new collection, from which you can then export.